# Why doesn't making the return type String allow me to return a string in a function

Tags: java

So what I expected this code to display on console was

> "hi"
>
> "Ken is a legend"
>
> "forkbomb"

```
public class ForkBombOnClick {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("hi");
    ken();
    System.out.println("fork bomb");
  }
  public static String ken() {
    return ("ken is a legend");
  }
}
```

But instead it only displays `hi` and `forkbomb`. When I change it to `public static void ken()` then it returns what I wanted the value to be but I was wondering. Why doesn't this current code work?

Comment: because you are not using what is returned by `ken()`

Comment: it does return it, but you don't do anything with the returned value. change ken(); with: System.out.println(ken());

Comment: In Java, we call `ken()` a method instead of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the string returned by method `ken();` like

```
System.out.println(ken());
```

Once a method returns something, you need to get hold of it to use it.

You can also use it like:

```
String returnValue = ken();
System.out.println(returnValue);
```

This will also yield same result.

Answer (score 1):

You know the answer yourself!

Why do you use `System.out.println`? To print on the screen string that you **pass to the function**.

You do it correctly by `System.out.println("hi");`, so it prints `hi`.

Now, you want to print string returned by `ken()` method. It has string as return type, so you can think of `ken();` invocation as a string. Just like `hi`.

So if you want to print it, you need to use `System.out.println` and supply result of `ken()` method to it, just like with other strings: `System.out.println(ken());`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `return` value in print statement which is string as `"ken is a legend"` .
Your final code should be like this ;

```
public class ForkBombOnClick {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi");
        System.out.println(ken());
        System.out.println("fork bomb");
    }

    public static String ken() {
        return "ken is a legend";
    }
}
```

or more clear version of code ;

```
public class ForkBombOnClick {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hi" + "\n" + ken() + "\n" + "fork bomb");
    }

    public static String ken() {
        return "ken is a legend";
    }
}
```

In this `System.out.println("hi" + "\n" + ken() + "\n" + "fork bomb");`

- `\n` refers to newline.